# How do auto email out reports every end of the month

Tags: email, civireport

I am trying to be able to send out a report automatically via email every month. Is there any possibility that I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about a CiviReport (under the Reports menu), then yes, you can do this from the Email Delivery tab of the report. Click the little ? there to see instructions for setting up a cron job to send the report monthly.